# How can I store multiple score values on Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know I can access the Score API to store the player's score on Facebook. My question is what if I want to score multiple score values, how can I do that?

For example, I want to store Highscore and Total Distance Travelled.
The way I'm doing now is:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", mScore], @"score",
                                   nil];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu/scores",
fbid] parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" 
      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)];
```

But this only allow me to store one value, because by calling the same thing again for other value, it will overwrite the old value.

Anyone know how can I store multiple values? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Facebook documentation - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/scores/:

> The Graph API for scores lets game developers publish game stories on news feed and timeline when a player earns a new high score or beats a friend's score.

Basically a user can currently have one score associated with an application, which works for games where there is just one high score, but not multiple.